# ng-click Function is call but the array data are not show In the HTML page in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

ng-click function is calling properly on a tab and i get the list from the service properly  but data are not reflect in the HTML page i don't understand what's the problem in my code please check my code and tell me which place i am wrong ?

```js
/**
 * @Summary:getUserCategory function, to get the User selected Category.
 * @param:   callback
 * @return:  callback(response) .
 * @Description: 
 */
//Defining function for getUserProfile in service 
$scope.getUserCategory = function () {
    var data = {
        userTypeKeyId: Number(AUTH.userTypeKeyId),
        fieldKeyId: Number(AUTH.defaultFieldKeyId)
    };
    IntermediaryDashboardService.getIntCategory(function (response) {
        if (response != null) {
            if (response.data.isSuccess) {
                $scope.userCategories = response.data.userCategories;
            }
        }
    }, data);
};


  /**
  * @Summary: getIntCategory function, to get the IntCategory
  * @param:   callback, data
  * @return: 
  * @Description:
  */ 
  this.getIntCategory = function (callback, data) {
   var url = '/api/userCategories/filter/list/each';
   $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: url,
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
      transformRequest: function(obj) {
        var str = [];
        for(var p in obj)
        str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
      return str.join("&");
      },
      data
    }).then(
      function (response) {
        //Success Function
        callback(response);
      },
      function (response) {
        //Failure function
        callback(null);
    }
   }
```

```html
<ul ng-repeat="category in userCategories" class="ng-cloak">
  <li style=" padding-top: 11px;">
    <a href="#" ng-click="getAlbumInIntermediary(category.categoryKeyId)">
      {{category.categoriesDto.categoryName}}
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Post `IntermediaryDashboardService ` content

Comment: So I guess `getUserCategory()` is the function that you say is being invoked. I just don't understand which data is not displayed - is it `$scope.userCategories` ?

Comment: change "intermediaryAlbumCount" in the html to "userCategories"

Comment: i call the getUserCategory() after click on the tab and i received $scope.userCategories  from the response this data are display in HTML page.

Comment: I don't see the place where you are trying to display your data, also where did you `console.log()` the data from, is it from `getIntCategory()` method ?

Comment: sir check my updated  code where i have to display the data.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple use**

```
ng-if="intermediaryAlbumCount.length"
```

**Because 0 is treated as falsy.**

Answer (score 0):

> but data are not display in the HTML page

Don't mix callbacks with Promises.

You do async call and resolving original Promise inside Service. So create new Promise and resolve it into your controller as:

```
 this.getIntCategory = function (callback, data) {

   var deferred = $q.defer(); 
   var url = '/api/userCategories/filter/list/each';
   $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: url,
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
      transformRequest: function(obj) {
        var str = [];
        for(var p in obj)
        str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
      return str.join("&");
      },
      data
    }).then(function (response) {
       deferred.resolve(response.data);
      },
      function (response) {
        deferred.resolve({});
    });
     return deferred.promise;
   }
```

And now in controller you can write as:

```
 $scope.getUserCategory = function () {           
    IntermediaryDashboardService.getIntCategory().then(function (result) {
          $scope.userCategories = response.data.userCategories;                           
    }, function (result) {
        alert("Error: No data returned");
     });    
  }
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u8gad5h1/)</kbd>

Comment: Max I'm sure that `,0)` is not required and is equivalent to `$timeout(function () {
   $scope.userCategories = response.data.userCategories;
});`

Comment: @codtex, yep, its just clear (at least for me) that we talk about timeout 0 msec :)

Comment: @codtex but i think he has other issue

Comment: Max both statements are true :)

Comment: sir its not working sir why we need $timeout function

Comment: Sir why we need deferred.resolve() here please explain me?

Comment: @kapilsoni because we create new promise and return it: `return deferred.promise;`. When HTTP response comes, we resolve it, its similar to callback

Comment: thank you sir for your great response i will try this code.

Comment: sir i am using this but response are not received from the service, only load after API call not show any data?

Comment: @kapilsoni so you have problem in other area

Comment: ok sir i will check but tell m in which condition this problem will be occur?